# How to make console flash after returning from function?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to write a CUI app where the window is supposed to flash **after** returning from a customized infunction. This would make it so that the flashing occurs after the input prompt is displayed, not beforehand.

My first idea was:

```py
from ctypes import windll

def custom_formatted_input():
    while get_foreground_window_title() != "cmd.exe":
        windll.user32.FlashWindow(windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), True)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    return input(f"""{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}{"".ljust(4)}[INPUT]{"".ljust(6)}{message} """)
```

where `get_foreground_window_title` is a Windows API call through ctypes.

This works, however this makes it so the input prompt is displayed whenever the flashing stops, i.e. after the user activates the cmd window.

How can I make it so that this flashing happens after the input function returns? I believe this would entail a decorator, however I couldn't figure the solution out on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Assign the result of the call to `input` to a variable then trigger the flash and finally return the saved result

Comment: @IainShelvington, if I save the value of input to a variable, that stops execution and waits for the input to be completed. So that will flash after the input prompt is completed by the user.

Comment: You want the flashing to _start_ when the input prompt is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Since execution always stops whenever `input()` is called, the flashing needs to occur while the execution is stopped, i.e. on another thread.

Code:

```py
def flash_window():
    while "cmd.exe" not in get_foreground_window_title():
        windll.user32.FlashWindow(windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), True)
        time.sleep(0.5)


def input_log(message):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=flash_window)
        t1.start()
        return input(f"""{time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}{"".ljust(4)}[INPUT]{"".ljust(6)}{message} """)
```